# Drools - jBPM 6.0.1 Final - Run as Stand Alone Application (Not using any application servers)?

Tags: persistence, drools, jbpm

Drools - JBPM 6.0.1.Final 
jBPM - Run as a stand alone application.

When constructing DefaultRuntimeEnvironment - It is throwing exception javax.persistence.Persistence classs methods are not abstract. It is not finding the implementation for this persistence.

I don't want to use persistence here. As jBPM is tightly integrated with persistence. I must provide these parameters.

I have provided everything. But still i am getting the exception related to persistence implemented jars.

How to avoid this? Is it mandatory to deploy the jBPM application in any application server.

I dont want to use any application server. I want to run as stand alone application in Spring Container.

Please assist.

Comment: What's the problem with including the required dependency jars? You don't need to be running in an application server to include the dependencies.

Comment: I must provide jboss jars to run properly. As far as i remember jBoss is not free. We are not supposed to use these jars in the application. Hence checking for the alternative in this path.

Comment: Persistence is not implemented by JBoss/jBPM ... it will be something such as Hibernate, which is open source.